# Is my INSERT INTO SELECT FROM statement in php correct?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL statement in PHP to move one row to another table but it keeps displaying:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
*

Here is my code:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"
INSERT INTO userdocs 
SELECT transaction_no
     , document_type
     , date_received
     , application_no
     , hei
     , school_name
     , from_co
     , other_govt
     , contact_person
     , comment
     , program
     , year_level
     , academic_year 
  FROM records 
 WHERE transaction_no = '$transaction_no'
");

if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))


            {  
                echo (mysqli_error($conn));
            }  

else
{
    echo "Document Sent! Going back to Home Page...";
    header("refresh:3; url=director.php");
}
```

Comment: your syntax is a little wrong, see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @smith there's nothing syntactically incorrect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the inclusion of `$transaction_no` results in a malformed statement. Try inspecting the SQL statement. Generally one should use prepared statements when dealing with dynamic parameters:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('insert into userdocs select transaction_no, document_type, date_received, application_no, hei, school_name, from_co, other_govt, contact_person, comment, program, year_level, academic_year from records where transaction_no = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('s', $transaction_no);

$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Or use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: What is the $db variable for?

Comment: It's just your `mysqli` object (`new mysqli(...)` or however you create your connection).